# Prevent execution of JUnit tests or forcing a special execution order of JUnit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, test-suite

Usually every JUnit test should be encapsulated, but I need to test if an encrypted file stored by EncryptorTest can be decrypted **by another Java VM instance** in DecryptorTest. You can manage this by running 2 different JUnit test classes **(not JUnit tests itself!)**. The only problem is that I have to guarantee that EncryptorTest runs before DecryptorTest (because the first one saves the file with the encrypted string). How can I do that? I thought about using a TestSuite:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({EncryptorTest.class, DecryptorTest.class})
public class EncrypterDecrypterTestSuite
{
}
```

But on server every JUnit test will run by itself too, so EncryptorTest and DecryptorTest can get mixed up. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit doesn't support the ordering of tests, you might want to use TestNG for this ([here is the relevant doc](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods)).

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. Unfortunately I have to run test classes in a special order, not the tests itself.

Comment: TestNG also supports class ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Typically JUnit is used for unit testing, so there shouldn't be dependencies between test cases.  You could use the `@Before` annotation to setup the encryption before the decryption or better yet, load an encryption file from the filesystem or feed it in programmatically.

Comment: That's what I do, loading it programmatically, but as I said, you can't guarantee that the decryption works properly when you run it in the same VM.  

UPDATE: Maybe my question was unclear. You have to run two different JUnit test classes to guarantee thqat 2 different VMs have been started. (I updated my question)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a different way, now. I omit the EncrypterTest and just encrypted the text in a file by myself and let the DecrypterTest read this file all the time. So I don't have to care about running it in different VMs.